# What is the most efficient way to spend Forge Points in FoE?

Tags: forge-of-empires

So I started with a blank slate in Forge of Empires and I was wondering if anyone knew the most efficient way to spend forge points to meet 1 or 2 of the following criteria

1. Get through the era/ages quickly
2. Maximize profits through era/ages

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Spend 5 on two tiers a day and that should get through Iron age fairly quickly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Unlock the Great Building participation tech in Iron Age, then start sniping your hood for forge points.
2. Save up several hundred in order to buy Arc goods and prints.
3. Begin leveling your Arc, and continue sniping.
4. Work in savings for purchasing CF goods and prints.
5. Join a 1.9 thread to help level your Arc.
6. Level Arc to 80.
7. Free fps.

Answer (score -1):

well there is many ways to do such, like say if you saw a building that was a great building, which no one has contributed to you contribute to it because you will get a gold reward this includes forage points and medals, let the owner build the rest and you will get lots of forage points on which to research a bit more.